# Contextual Action Mode for listview

Tags: android, listview, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

(+):pros
(-):cons

1. Enabling the contextual action mode for individual views:

   (+) Can trigger contextual action bar (CAB) by clicking on particular view.

   (-) Do not provide onItemCheckedStateChanged() method to set title of number of selected items from listview.
2. Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView or GridView:

   (+) Do provide onItemCheckedStateChanged()

   (-) Cannot trigger CAB by clicking on particular view.

**Question:** I want to trigger CAB by clicking on particular view (i.e "select" button from menu) AND allow to set title of number of selected items from listview.
I greatly appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you!